# Installing Linux Mint on free space

Tags: linux-mint

I have a 1TB hard drive which is mostly empty. I've shrunk the partition in Windows Disk Management by about 200GB which I want to use for my Linux Mint installation. The installer looks like this:

[image]

If I click `Install Now` will that take care of the installation for me? I read people mentioning using LVM and other things to create swap space and things so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations for choosing **Linux**, embrace the freedom

No It won't handle the installation. Here's what you need to do, first create a swap volume and the size should be about the size of your RAM. I just read that having the swap space twice the RAM is a old school rule, back in the days when things don't function so well.

1. Create Swap space
2. Create ext3/ext4 partition and choose `/` under`Mount location`
3. Create another ext3/ext4 partition and choose `/home` as `Mount Location` (Optional)

*Reason for home : If there is something wrong with your os, you can relax knowing that you saved that 4000 words essay inside home directory*

And press install while selecting the root partition.